# Class not found IOS NSURLDownload.h

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm trying to import this class header #import `<Foundation/NSURLDownload.h>` and I'm getting error File not found but I have it on my build path the foundation framework. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class is only available for Mac OS X, not iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a mac osx class not an ios class, therefore you won't be able to find it.